# VB.Net Login form using SQL Server with Roles that redirect to different forms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I'm currently working on an employee management system on VB.net and SQL Server as the database.

This is what my current database table looks like:

[image]

This is what the login form looks like:

[image]

I want this login form and that single login button to accommodate both admin and employee roles. Each roles go to different forms. This is what my current code looks like:

```
Private Sub logIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonLogin.Click
        Dim connectionLogin As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        sqlLogin = "SELECT (1000) [Login]
      ,[Password]
      ,[Role]
  FROM [RestaurantDatabase].[dbo].[Login] where  Login ='" & txtUsername.Text & "'"
        connectionLogin.Open()
        sAdapterLogin = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlLogin, connectionLogin)
        SDsLogin = New DataSet()
        sAdapterLogin.Fill(SDsLogin, "login")
        sTableLogin = SDsLogin.Tables("login")
        If sTableLogin.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username", "Unauthorized", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        Else
            If sTableLogin.Rows.Item(0).Item("Password") = txtPassword.Text Then
                formTasks.Show()

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password entered", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

How do I do this? My current code doesn't take into consideration the roles. Both admin and employees get redirected to the same form.

Comment: Let me stop you there.... you're running on windows right? I recommend that rather than cooking up your own identity and authroisation system, that you at least use windows authentication, and preferably, also windows groups to do this. No matter how colourful your login screen is, it's annoying to think up YAP (yet another password). If this is an experiment or you're not on a window environment, you can ignore this comment

Comment: Regardless, please post your code as text, not as a picture

Comment: The short answer to your question is that you use the `Role` value that you are capturing in your login screen to decide what role the person is

Comment: will remove the picture and replace with codes, sorry for that.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid how do I do that? I'm pretty new with vb.net and mssql

Comment: Well... it's not something that can be simply explained. Maybe save it for the next phase of your project. It's called "Single Sign On" and it means your users only need to sign on to windows once and they don't have to remember any more logins or passwords.

Comment: In answer to your question you'd use something like `if sTableLogin.Rows.Item(0).Item("Role") = "Admin" Then formAdmin.Show()`. But basically there's a a lot of issues with your existing code but start with that

Comment: Do NOT use three-part names in your sql code without a very good reason and without understanding how fragile this makes your code. Generally, your connection determines the database to use for any object references like tables. And why `SELECT (1000) [Login]...` ? THINK about the code you write (or copy/paste from another tool).

Comment: Going by your comments here, you're going to have to at least learn to debug. That is, step through your code and inspect the program flow as it runs. Inspect variable values in real time. Also if code looks too complicate for you, that is your cue to get on google and try and understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database objects like `Connection`, `Command` and `DataReader` use unmanaged code. The authors of these classes have provided a `Dispose` method to release unmanaged resource. We must call `Dispose` on these objects. Luckily, vb.net provides `Using...End Using` blocks to take care of this for us. The `Using` block also closes the `Connection`. To include more than one object in a `Using` block separate them by a comma.

It is not good practice to have the name of your table the same as the name of a field. (Login)

**NEVER** concatenate string to build sql command text. This leaves you wide open to sql injection. This means that a user could insert executable code in a text box and damage your database. **Always** use parameters. Sql Server does not consider parameter values as executable.

If you select the role and pass the user and password to Sql Server, you will only need to retrieve a single piece of data. `ExecuteScalar` does this by returning the first column of the first row of the result set. You don't need a `DataAdapter` or `DataSet`.

Only after the connection is closed, do we check for validity and act on the value of role.

```
Private Sub logIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonLogin.Click
    Dim SqlLogin = "SELECT [Role]
                    FROM [RestaurantDatabase].[dbo].[Login] 
                    Where  [Login] = @User And [Password] = @Password;"
    Dim role As String = ""
    Using connectionLogin As New SqlConnection(connectionstring),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(SqlLogin, connectionLogin)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text
        connectionLogin.Open()
        role = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using 'closed the Connection and disposes the Connection and Command

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(role) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials", "Unauthorized", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
    Else
        If role = "Admin" Then
            'Show the admin form
        Else
            'Show the employee form
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have not dealt with this here but passwords should **NEVER** be stored as plain text. This is to protect your user and your database. Password should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the answer to the question is
Can't we just add the conditional code below?

```
Private Sub logIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonLogin.Click
        Dim connectionLogin As New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        sqlLogin = "SELECT (1000) [Login]
      ,[Password]
      ,[Role]
  FROM [RestaurantDatabase].[dbo].[Login] where  Login ='" & txtUsername.Text & "'"
        connectionLogin.Open()
        sAdapterLogin = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlLogin, connectionLogin)
        SDsLogin = New DataSet()
        sAdapterLogin.Fill(SDsLogin, "login")
        sTableLogin = SDsLogin.Tables("login")
        If sTableLogin.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username", "Unauthorized", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        Else
            If sTableLogin.Rows.Item(0).Item("Password") = txtPassword.Text Then
             
                if  sTableLogin.Rows.Item(0).Item("Role") ="Admin"
                  ''' admin form show
                else
                 ''' order form show
                end if

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password entered", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code somehow doesn't check for the admin role. It just goes to order form immediately

Comment: I think the instruction is wrong there. IMO should be `if sTableLogin.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString() == "Admin"`. I can post an example, although in C#

Answer (score 1):

Regarding my comment to @Think2826 answer, see the example code below:

```cs
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Role", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(1, "john smith", "admin");

var isAdmin = table.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString() == "admin";
Console.WriteLine($"User '{table.Rows[0]["Name"]}' is admin: {isAdmin}");
```

I think in VB that would be something like:

```
Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()
table.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
table.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
table.Columns.Add("Role", GetType(String))
table.Rows.Add(New Object() { 1, "john smith", "admin" })
Dim isAdmin As Boolean = table.Rows(0)("Role").ToString() = "admin"
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("User '{0}' is admin: {1}", table.Rows(0)("Name"), isAdmin))
```

On top of that, what you're doing is very risky - your code is pretty much SQL Injection vulnerable. You should use SQL parameters before sending our your `sqlLogin` query to the database.
And I agree with @Nick.McDermaid, SSO might be an overkill at this point, but it's worth considering for the future.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get the code. It looks complicated

Comment: I did the one that you commented on @Think2826. But I got an error called  "Value of type 'DataRowCollection' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'"

Comment: Try `if sTableLogin.Rows(0)("Role").ToString() = "Admin"` and it should be OK.

Comment: yeah I already tried this but sadly it didn't work. It keeps redirecting to the employee form.

Comment: Change the text in your USERNAME label to `sTableLogin.Rows(0).("Role").ToString()` and do not show any form. Thanks to this you will see what Role was retrieved from the database. If you're getting redirected to the employee form it means you're not receiving "admin" string from the database.